# Построение карты Choropleth с помощью Folium

Tags: python-3.x, geojson

Я использовал код из статьи https://www.jpytr.com/post/analysinggeographicdatawithfolium/ с целью нарисовать сетку поверх карты folium.

Следующая функция генерит geojson с координатами ячеек:

```
def get_geojson_grid(upper_right, lower_left, n=6):
    """Returns a grid of geojson rectangles, and computes the exposure 
        in each section of the grid based on the vessel data.

    Parameters
    ----------
    upper_right: array_like
        The upper right hand corner of "grid of grids" (the default is 
   the upper right hand [lat, lon] of the USA).

    lower_left: array_like
        The lower left hand corner of "grid of grids"  (the default is 
     the lower left hand [lat, lon] of the USA).

    n: integer
        The number of rows/columns in the (n,n) grid.

    Returns
    -------

    list
        List of "geojson style" dictionary objects   
    """

    all_boxes = []

    lat_steps = np.linspace(lower_left[0], upper_right[0], n+1)
    lon_steps = np.linspace(lower_left[1], upper_right[1], n+1)

    lat_stride = lat_steps[1] - lat_steps[0]
    lon_stride = lon_steps[1] - lon_steps[0]

    for lat in lat_steps[:-1]:
        for lon in lon_steps[:-1]:
            # Define dimensions of box in grid
            upper_left = [lon, lat + lat_stride]
            upper_right = [lon + lon_stride, lat + lat_stride]
            lower_right = [lon + lon_stride, lat]
            lower_left = [lon, lat]

            # Define json coordinates for polygon
            coordinates = [
                upper_left,
                upper_right,
                lower_right,
                lower_left,
                upper_left
            ]

            geo_json = {"type": "FeatureCollection",
                        "properties":{
                            "lower_left": lower_left,
                            "upper_right": upper_right
                        },
                        "features":[]}

            grid_feature = {
                "type":"Feature",
                "geometry":{
                    "type":"Polygon",
                    "coordinates": [coordinates],
                }
            }

            geo_json["features"].append(grid_feature)

            all_boxes.append(geo_json)

    return all_boxes
```

Следующий код - выводит сетку.

```
lower_left = [49.68, -7.669]
upper_right = [59.145, 2.77]
m = folium.Map(zoom_start = 5, location=[55, 0])
grid = get_geojson_grid(upper_right, lower_left , n=6)

for i, geo_json in enumerate(grid):

    color = plt.cm.Reds(i / len(grid))
    color = mpl.colors.to_hex(color)

    gj = folium.GeoJson(geo_json,
                        style_function=lambda feature, color=color: {'fillColor': color, 'color':"black", 'weight': 2, 'dashArray': '5, 5', 'fillOpacity': 0.55,
                                                                    }) 
    popup = folium.Popup("example popup {}".format(i))
    gj.add_child(popup)

    m.add_child(gj)
m
```

Проблема состоит в том, что мне нужна сетка 50х50, но если в функции get_geojson_grid указываю n>30 то ничего не выводится - просто пустая ячейка в Jupiter ноутбуке. Если ввожу n меньше - все отлично работает. В чем проблема не пойму.

Comment: I am wildly sorry, but this resource is for the Russian language. Please translate the content into Russian, or go to the [English version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions) of the resource.

Answer (score 0):

Нашел ответ на собственный вопрос. 
Jupiter не рендерит большое количество объектов в Chrome. Надо использовать Firefox или Safari - все работает!